# How to give relative path of Powershell script that is intended to be executed in Jenkins Powershell plugin

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to know how to specify the path of my Powershell script in Jenkins plugin for Powershell.
I know I can write Powershell commands directly here, but I want to specify a path which is relative to the Jenkins workspace folder.
I tried to specify it like this:
[image]

Comment: you can use the built-in environment variable pointing to the workspace : powershell -File "${WORKSPACE}\project\etc\file.ps1". As a good practice, avoid any spaces in folder and file names.

Answer (score 0):

I got the variable for workspace. This is available in Jenkins in Powershell Job just below the command box -   See the list of available environment variables

$env:WORKSPACE is the Variable name.

Usage - 
powershell -File $env:WORKSPACE\Users\FileToRun.ps1 -Verb RunAs